# Default Routes not redirecting to expected page in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `HomeController` in which I have 2 `ActionResults` say `Index` and `Projects`. Now my `RouteConfig.cs` has below routes added:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default_1",//Changed this to some other name
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",//Made this name as Default
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Projects", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So from the above configuration I was expecting by the default the user will redirected to `/Home/Projects`. But again it is redirecting to `Index` action. **Why it is not redirecting to `Projects` action? Can't we have multiple routes here?`Default` name will not be considered as default url?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register your routes,put your specific route definition(s) before the default route definition. **The order of route registration matters**.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Project",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Projects", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);    

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

With this configuration, Any requests coming will be redirected to your `Home/Projects` because the url pattern is still the generic pattern(`{controller}/{action}/{id}`). So i guess you really meant something like this.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Project",
    url: "projects/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Projects", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);    

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This will send the request `http://yourSite.com/Projects` to `Home/Projects`

Or you may use attribute routing to define this route pattern in the Projects controller.To enable attribute routing, you can call the `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` method in the `RegisterRoutes` method of `RouteConfig.cs`. You will still keep the default route definition there.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

    );
}
```

And in your ProjectsController

```
[Route("Projects/{id?}")]
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
   //check id value  and return something
}
```

Comment: Bingo!!.. Thanks alot buddy.. :) Accepting answer in 12 minutes.. :)

Comment: No no.. My default action to be executed first in the `HomeController` should be `Projects` when I put `http://yoursite.com`. I think I presented it in wrong way.. You first method solves my problem.. But yea got something new to learn..

Comment: I see. Then it makes sense.

Comment: But one doubt here.. I get error when I use this `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` and error says **system.web.routing.routecollection does not contain a definition for MapMvcAttributeRoutes**

Comment: It is defined in `System.Web.Mvc` assembly. Make sure you added a reference to that. https://www.nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting/